# Estimation of fixed effects and interactions in a mixed linear model analysis

Tags: mixed-model, model, linear

In my data (from an experiment in psychology) I would like to test a model with three fixed factors and two random factors. 
The three fixed factors are categorical, two with 2 levels and one with three levels [ a 2 (var A) x 2 (var B) x 3 (var C) model].
The random effects are participants and stimuli. I am using the lme4 package in R to estimate the model.

I want to estimate all the fixed effects (3 main effects, 3 two-way interactions and one three-way interaction) within the same model. 
To the best of my understanding, in order to estimate the main effects and two-way interactions rather than the simple effects and simple two-way interactions, I need to center all the fixed variable before entering them into the model. 
However, while it is possible to center a categorical variable with two levels (by giving a 0.5 and a -0.5 values to its levels), I do not know how to center a categorical variable with 3 levels.

Is it possible to estimate all the main effects and interactions within a single model in this case?
A demonstration of the answer with an R-code would be appreciated.